# How to connect to UNIDATA on Unix with uniobject for java

Tags: java, php, unix, unidata, uniobjects

Can someone tell me the how to establish a connection to a UniData database that is on Unix with the UniObjects for Java API?

Also does any know if this is possible with JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Check out our GitHub repository and you will find code to help. Only difference between Unix & Windows is the account path you use when connecting.

https://github.com/RocketSoftware/u2-servers-lab/blob/master/UOJ-Demos/UOJ%20Connect/uojconnect.java

There is a Java bridge available for PHP which will enable you to do it using UniObjects for Java.

I would strongly recommend *not* connecting directly to your database via JavaScript. The UniRPC port should not be exposed to clients, as a general 'best practices' for security. The UniRPC port is what UniObjects, along with several other database services, initiate connections on.